# What exactly is a Class Factory?

Tags: class, factory

I see the word thrown around often, and I may have used it myself in code and libraries over time, but I never really got it. In most write-ups I came across, they just went on expecting you to figure it out.

What is a Class Factory? Can someone explain the concept?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A class factory constructs instances of other classes. Typically, the classes they create share a common base class or interface, but derived classes are returned.

For example, you could have a class factory that took a database connection string and returned a class implementing `IDbConnection` such as `SqlConnection` (class and interface from .Net)

Comment: Does it have to construct class instances? Or can it just return classes, that can be instantiated later? If only the former, is there a name for the latter?

Comment: An object factory returns class instances.   A class factory returns classes (classes are templates for objects)

Answer (score 35):

Here's some supplemental information that may help better understand several of the other shorter, although technically correct, answers.

In the strictest sense a Class Factory is a function or method that creates or selects a class and returns it, based on some condition determined from input parameters or global context. This is required when the *type* of object needed can't be determined until runtime. Implementation can be done directly when classes are themselves objects in the language being used, such as Python.

Since the primary use of any class is to create instances of itself, in languages such as C++ where classes are not objects that can be passed around and manipulated, a similar result can often be achieved by simulating "virtual constructors", where you call a base-class constructor but get back an instance of some derived class. This must be simulated because constructors can't really be [virtual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function)<sup>**✶**</sup> in C++, which is why such *object*—not class—factories are usually implemented as standalone functions or static methods.

Although using object-factories is a simple and straight-forward scheme, they require the manual maintenance of a list of all supported types in the base class' `make_object()` function, which can be error-prone and labor-intensive (if not over-looked). It also violates encapsulation<sup>**✶✶**</sup> since a member of base class must know about all of the base's concrete descendant classes (now and in the future).

<sup>**✶** Virtual functions are normally resolved "[late](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding)" by the actual type of object referenced, but in the case of constructors, the object doesn't exist yet, so the type must be determined by some other means.</sup>
<sup>**✶✶** [Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) is a property of the design of a set of classes and functions where the knowledge of the implementation details of a particular class or function are hidden within it—and is one of the hallmarks of object-oriented programming.</sup>

Therefore the best/ideal implementations are those that can handle new candidate classes *automatically* when they're added, rather than having only a certain finite set currently hardcoded into the factory (although the trade-off is often deemed acceptable since the factory is the only place requiring modification).

James Coplien's 1991 book [***Advanced C++: Programming Styles and Idioms***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201548550) has details on one way to implement such virtual generic constructors in C++. There are even better ways to do this using [C++ templates](http://web.archive.org/web/20010216204456id_/http://www.kirkrader.com/writing/technical/cpp.htm#virtual_constructors), but that's not covered in the book which predates their addition to the standard language definition. In fact, C++ templates are themselves class factories since they instantiate a new class whenever they're invoked with different actual type arguments.
**Update:** I located a 1998 paper Coplien wrote for EuroPLoP titled [***C++ Idioms***](http://web.archive.org/web/20080807045811im_/http://users.rcn.com:80/jcoplien/Patterns/C++Idioms/EuroPLoP98.html) where, among other things, he revises and regroups the idioms in his book into design-pattern form à la the 1994 [***Design Patterns: Elements of Re-Usable Object-Oriented Software***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) book. Note especially the [Virtual Constructor](http://web.archive.org/web/20080807045811im_/http://users.rcn.com:80/jcoplien/Patterns/C++Idioms/EuroPLoP98.html#VirtualConstructor) section (which uses his [Envelope/Letter](http://web.archive.org/web/20080807045811im_/http://users.rcn.com:80/jcoplien/Patterns/C++Idioms/EuroPLoP98.html#EnvelopeLetter) pattern structure).

Also see the related answers here to the question [Class factory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456672/class-factory-in-python) as well as the 2001 Dr. Dobb's article about implementing them with C++ Templates titled [*Abstract Factory, Template Style*](http://www.drdobbs.com/conversations-abstract-factory-template/184403786).

Comment: For an example of what I think is a good way to implement virtual constructors in Python, see my answer to the question [Improper use of `__new__` to generate classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035685/improper-use-of-new-to-generate-classes)

Answer (score 10):

A class factory is a method which (according to some parameters for example) returns you a customised class (not instantiated!).

Comment: Is there a book or link where one can learn more about Class Factory? I can't find much information abot this pattern.

Answer (score 4):

The Wikipedia article gives a pretty good definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern

But probably the most authoritative definition would be found in the *Design Patterns* book by Gamma et al. (commonly called the Gang of Four Book).

Answer (score 2):

I felt that this explains it pretty well (for me, anyway). Class factories are used in the factory design pattern, I think.

> Like other creational patterns, it [the factory design pattern]
>   deals with the problem of creating
>   objects (products) without specifying
>   the exact class of object that will be
>   created. The factory method design
>   pattern handles this problem by
>   defining a separate method for
>   creating the objects, which subclasses
>   can then override to specify the
>   derived type of product that will be
>   created. More generally, the term
>   factory method is often used to refer
>   to any method whose main purpose is
>   creation of objects.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Apologies if you've already read this and found it to be insufficient.