# Using a class' __new__ method as a Factory: __init__ gets called twice

Tags: python, design-patterns, inheritance, class-design

I encountered a strange bug in python where using the `__new__` method of a class as a factory would lead to the `__init__` method of the instantiated class to be called twice.

The idea was originally to use the `__new__` method of the mother class to return a specific instance of one of her children depending on the parameters that are passed, without having to declare a factory function outside of the class.

I know that using a factory function would be the best design-pattern to use here, but changing the design pattern at this point of the project would be costly. My question hence is: is there a way to avoid the double call to `__init__` and get only a single call to `__init__` in such a schema ?

```
class Shape(object):
    def __new__(cls, desc):
        if cls is Shape:
            if desc == 'big':   return Rectangle(desc)
            if desc == 'small': return Triangle(desc)
        else:
            return super(Shape, cls).__new__(cls, desc)

    def __init__(self, desc):
        print "init called"
        self.desc = desc

class Triangle(Shape):
    @property
    def number_of_edges(self): return 3

class Rectangle(Shape):
    @property
    def number_of_edges(self): return 4

instance = Shape('small')
print instance.number_of_edges

>>> init called
>>> init called
>>> 3
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

When you construct an object Python calls its `__new__` method to create the object then calls `__init__` on the object that is returned. When you create the object from inside `__new__` by calling `Triangle()` that will result in further calls to `__new__` and `__init__`.

What you should do is:

```
class Shape(object):
    def __new__(cls, desc):
        if cls is Shape:
            if desc == 'big':   return super(Shape, cls).__new__(Rectangle)
            if desc == 'small': return super(Shape, cls).__new__(Triangle)
        else:
            return super(Shape, cls).__new__(cls, desc)
```

which will create a `Rectangle` or `Triangle` without triggering a call to `__init__` and then `__init__` is called only once.

Edit to answer @Adrian's question about how super works:

`super(Shape,cls)` searches `cls.__mro__` to find `Shape` and then searches down the remainder of the sequence to find the attribute.

`Triangle.__mro__` is `(Triangle, Shape, object)` and
`Rectangle.__mro__` is `(Rectangle, Shape, object)` while `Shape.__mro__` is just `(Shape, object)`.
For any of those cases when you call `super(Shape, cls)` it ignores everything in the mro squence up to and including `Shape` so the only thing left is the single element tuple `(object,)` and that is used to find the desired attribute.

This would get more complicated if you had a diamond inheritance:

```
class A(object): pass
class B(A): pass
class C(A): pass
class D(B,C): pass
```

now a method in B might use `super(B, cls)` and if it were a B instance would search `(A, object)` but if you had a `D` instance the same call in `B` would search `(C, A, object)` because the `D.__mro__` is `(B, C, A, object)`.

So in this particular case you could define a new mixin class that modifies the construction behaviour of the shapes and you could have specialised triangles and rectangles inheriting from the existing ones but constructed differently.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `return Rectangle.__new__(Rectangle)` because this would guarantee that `__new__` of `Rectangle` gets called if it's defined?

Comment: @Georg, If you do that you are going to have to be pretty careful to avoid infinite recursion. Any class specific initialisation should be in `__init__` so I think it is pretty safe here to assume that `__new__`'s only job is to create an object of the correct type.

Comment: The code in your answer fixes the problem but doesn't explain why `Shape.__init__()` was called twice in the OP's code, even when `Shape.__new__()` returns a `Triangle(desc)`. This seems contrary to what the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__new__#basic-customization) say: "If `__new__()` does not return an instance of `cls`, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will _not_ be invoked."

Comment: Never mind, I'm guessing in the OP's code it's `isinstance(<returned object>, Shape)` being `True` for a `Triangle` object that's allowing the `Shape.__init__()` method to be called on it.

Comment: @martineau: Precisely, `__init__` is called if the returned object is an instance of the specified class _or a subclass_. (It's my frank opinion that this is a Bad Thing, but alas, it's the way it is.)

Comment: @GeorgSchölly `super(Shape, cls)` - in general, how does `super` use the first and second arguments to return the thing it returns? [I know `cls` must be a subclass of `Shape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) but how does the thing that `super` returns relate to `Shape` and `cls`?

Comment: @Adrian: I don't know all the details of super by heart, but you can have a look [at the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) or [the code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/typeobject.c#l7129). It must be something like this: `super(Class, instance).method(args)` is the same as `Class.method(instance, args)` where `instance` is usually called `self` inside the method.

Comment: @Adrian, I added a description of how `super` works.

Comment: What would be the equivalent in python 3?

Answer (score 15):

After posting my question, I continued searching for a solution an found a way to solve the problem that looks like a bit of a hack. It is inferior to Duncan's solution, but I thought it could be interesting to mention none the less. The `Shape`class becomes:

```
class ShapeFactory(type):
    def __call__(cls, desc):
        if cls is Shape:
            if desc == 'big':   return Rectangle(desc)
            if desc == 'small': return Triangle(desc)
        return type.__call__(cls, desc)

class Shape(object):
    __metaclass__ = ShapeFactory 
    def __init__(self, desc):
        print "init called"
        self.desc = desc
```

Comment: Why do you say this is inferior to Duncan's solution. This seems much clearer to what's going on, imo less hacky. Also meta.

Comment: I thought it was less obvious because it adds a fourth class to the program and involves the `__metaclass__` black magic that not everyone is familiar with.

Comment: Although most folks probably don't care, one advantage of using inheritance instead of a metaclass is that the syntax for specifying metaclasses is different in Python 3 that it is in Python 2—on the other hand, inheritance is written similarly in both of them. That fact could make it a better fit when attempting to write code that will work unchanged in both versions of Python.

Comment: IMHO having metaclass is cleaner because here, one is trying to implemented a top down inheritence (creating child from parents) instead of the normal inheritance order down-top (creating parents from child). Metaclass seems to be the right way to do it :) Also, the whole purpose of `call`and `new` is to deal with such cases...

Answer (score -2):

I can't actually reproduce this behavior in either of the Python interpreters I have installed, so this is something of a guess. However...

`__init__` is being called twice because you are initializing two objects: the original `Shape` object, and then one of its subclasess.  If you change your `__init__` so it also prints the class of the object being initialized, you will see this.

```
print type(self), "init called"
```

This is harmless because the original `Shape` will be discarded, since you are not returning a reference to it in your `__new__()`.

Since calling a function is *syntactically identical* to instantiating a class, you can change this to a function without changing anything else, and I recommend that you do exactly that. I don't understand your reluctance.

Comment: This is not correct - the first `__init__` call happens *inside* the outer `__new__` call (when `Triangle()` and `Rectangle()` are called), but then, because an instance of `Shape` is returned by `__new__`, the original `Shape()` call invokes `__init__` *again* on that already initialised object. Note that if the object returned by `__new__()` is *not* an instance of `Shape()` then `__init__` won't be called (which can foul up attempts to observe this behaviour if the class hierarchy isn't right).

Comment: Indeed, both are syntactically identical. My reluctance stems from the fact that if I define a function called "Shape", I must rename my class to something like "_Shape". This will cause some variable renaming, of course, but mostly it will have complicated consequences on other things like the documentation that is generated by sphinx-autodoc.

Comment: I suppose you do want to expose documentation on those classes so you can't just declare them *in* the function. You might try just reassigning the instance's `__class__` attribute in `__init__()` and not messing with `__new__()` at all.

Comment: ... one of the pitfalls of this, by the way, is that you will have to manually re-bind the instance methods from the correct class to the instance.

Comment: Another approach might be to use a metaclass to override the `__call__()` method on the class, so that the `()` syntax does not necessarily instantiate the class.

Comment: ... in fact, the metaclass approach does work, but the solution you accepted is much simpler.