# What's the use case for __new__ method to return an object of a different type than its first arg?

Tags: python, class, object, constructor

The documentation [implies that it's ok](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__new__#object.__new__) for `__new__(cls, ...)` to return an object of a type different than `cls`. It says in that case `__init__()` won't be called. It's not stated explicitly, but common sense or a simple test confirms that the resulting the object won't have type `cls`.

Why is this seemingly strange behavior allowed? What's the use case? It's clearly intentional.

Comment: Is there a need to *force* you not to be able to do it? Python generally doesn't stop you doing something unless there is a need to do so.

Comment: If it just worked silently as if nothing happened, I would think it's just as you said - Python letting me do whatever. But Python actually *does* check the type of the returned object; and if it's not the same as `cls`, it modifies the default behavior (specifically, skips the call to `__init__`). It's clear that it's intended to serve some mysterious (to me) purpose.

Comment: There are cases in the standard library where a constructor does not return an instance of its type. E.g., `isinstance(int(2**1024), int)` evaluates to `False`.

Comment: @larsmans: that evaluates to `True` in python 3.  The old behaviour is just confusing (presumably that is why they changed it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be useful when you create mock objects for unit testing.

You can change the `__new__` method to return, in the certain cases, the the other object with the same interface, as original (for example simulating the original class instances' behaviour), without modifications to the rest of code.

Comment: Neat. This is a clean and simple use case.

Comment: It's also a elegant way to implement [object factories](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5953974/355230).

Answer (score 4):

I guess the Python folks just decided that there is no reason to enforce `__new__(cls, ...)` to return instances of `cls`.  `__new__` is a fairly advanced method, so the user probably knows what he's doing, and there *could* be some reasons to exploit this behavior.

They still have to do the check, though.  During instance creation, `__init__` should be called.  This is only reasonable if the instance (returned from `__new__`) really is a `cls`.  If `__new__` returns something different, chances are that the object cannot handle the arguments that would be passed to `__init__`.

In the end, the addition of `__new__` to the language left the developers with three choices:

1. Enforce `__new__(cls, ...)` to return an instance of `cls`
2. Always call `__init__` on the instance returned by `__new__`, leaving it up to the user to ensure that the object can handle the arguments.
3. Only call `__init__` if the instance really is an instance of `cls`.

I guess that option 3 seemed most practical.

Comment: Ahh of course, I forgot that the arguments to `new_instance.__init__` would most likely mismatch when `type(new_instance) != cls`. And it would be very hard for the developer to address this; since it's not like he has any control over what arguments are passed to `__init__` does he?