# python dataclasses with optional attributes

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

How do you make Optional attr's of a dataclass?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class CampingEquipment:
    knife: bool
    fork: bool
    missing_flask_size: # what to write here?
    
kennys_stuff = {
    'knife': True,
    'fork': True
}

print(CampingEquipment(**kennys_stuff))
```

I tried `field(init=False)`, but it gave me:

```
TypeError: CampingEquipment.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'missing_flask_size'
```

By Optional I mean `__dict__` may contain the key "missing_flask_size" or not.  If I set a default value then the key will be there and it shouldn't be in some cases.  I want to check its type if it is there.

I tried moving the `field(init=False)` to the type location (after the colon) so I could make it more explicit as to the thing I wanted optional would be the key and not the value.

So I want this test to pass:

```
with pytest.raises(AttributeError):
    ce = CampingEquipment(**kennys_stuff)
    print(ce.missing_flask_size)
```

Comment: Got it, so it looks like a current answer already addresses this issue, in that case. Also, wondering what’s the type of the optional field? If user were to pass it in to consutector I mean.

Comment: There is a lot of good information but the existing answers don't look like they answer the question.  It could be that a data class is more like sql which have column names for everything in the table or not.

Comment: in Python `3.10+` you could have optional types with `Optional[X]`  or  `X | None` (or `Union[X, None]`).

Comment: @irajjelodari That's not what OP intends with "optional". The `Optional` type hint means that the value can be `None`. What OP means with "optional" is that the variable is not in `__dict__` at all, not that it is there but has a `None` value.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's not possible to use a dataclass to make an attribute that sometimes exists and sometimes doesn't because the generated [`__init__`](https://www.pythonmorsels.com/what-is-init/), [`__eq__`](https://www.pythonmorsels.com/overloading-equality-in-python/), `__repr__`, etc hard-code which attributes they check.

However, it is possible to make a dataclass with an optional argument that uses a default value for an attribute (when it's not provided).

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class CampingEquipment:
    knife: bool
    fork: bool
    missing_flask_size: Optional[int] = None
    
kennys_stuff = {
    'knife':True,
    'fork': True
}

print(CampingEquipment(**kennys_stuff))
```

And it's possible to make a dataclass with an argument that's accepted to `__init__` but isn't an *actual field*.
So you could do something like this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class CampingEquipment:
    knife: bool
    fork: bool
    missing_flask_size: InitVar[Optional[int]] = None

    def __post_init__(self, missing_flask_size):
        if missing_flask_size is not None:
            self.missing_flask_size = missing_flask_size
```

If you *really* want classes to either to have that attribute present or not have it at all, you could subclass your dataclass and make a factory function that creates one class or the other based on whether that `missing_flask_size` attribute is present:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class CampingEquipment:
    knife: bool
    fork: bool


@dataclass
class CampingEquipmentWithFlask:
    missing_flask_size: int


def equipment(**fields):
    if 'missing_flask_size' in fields:
        return CampingEquipmentWithFlask(**fields)
    return CampingEquipment(**fields)
    

kennys_stuff = {
    'knife':True,
    'fork': True
}

print(CampingEquipment(**kennys_stuff))
```

If you *really* wanted to (I wouldn't recommend it though), you could even customize the [`__new__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206124/whats-the-use-case-for-new-method-to-return-an-object-of-a-different-type-t) of `CampingEquipment` to return an instance of that special subclass when that `missing_flask_size` argument is given (though then you'd need to set `init=False` and make your own `__init__` as well on that class).

Answer (score 14):

A `field` object is supposed to be used with `=`, like a default value, not `:` like an annotation.

Specifying `init=False` for a field means the caller can't pass in a value for it at all. `init=False` fields are supposed to be set in `__post_init__`, [like this](https://ideone.com/Z29y6i):

```
@dataclass
class Example:
    a: int
    b: int
    c: int = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.c = self.a + self.b

print(Example(1, 2).c) # prints 3
```

If you want to make it *optional* for the caller to provide a value, you can set a default value. If the caller doesn't provide a value, [the default will be used instead](https://ideone.com/x5ZHeZ):

```
@dataclass
class Example:
    a: int
    b: int
    c: int = -1

print(Example(1, 2).c) # prints -1
print(Example(1, 2, 3).c) # prints 3
```

Comment: I'd also mention `field(default=...)` and in the case of mutable types, `field(default_factory=...)`, additionally as it's unclear what the type of the last field in the OP was.

Answer (score -2):

Just add a value to optional field

```
@dataclass
class CampingEquipment:
   knife: bool
   fork: bool
   missing_flask_size: int = field(default=None)

# CampingEquipment(knife=True, fork=True, missing_flask_size=None)
```

See this post too [How to create an optional field in a dataclass that is inherited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61522624/how-to-create-an-optional-field-in-a-dataclass-that-is-inherited)

Comment: That's not how `field` is supposed to be used.

Comment: But after edit, it’s still not right. Because dataclasses relies on type annotations to determine fields, so right now you are defining a class (static) variable, not a dataclass field.

Answer (score -2):

I was also looking for the same and find a workaround. Simply pop the item that you don't want if conditional. like this

```
@dataclass
class Element:
    type: str
    src: str
    scale: Scale 
    duration: float = -1
    start: float = 0
    extra_time: float = 0
    cache: bool = True

    def get_data(self) -> None:
        if self.type != "image":
            self.__dict__.pop('scale')
            return self.__dict__
        if self.type == "image":
            return self.__dict__
```

Simply pop the item that you don't want with conditional and call this method get_data(). Hope this will help.

Comment: This will modify the instance data itself whenever `get_data` is called; critically, calling `get_data` twice when the `type` is not `"image"` will fail because there is no `scale` to `pop` the second time!