# UnboundLocalError with closure in Python

Tags: python, closures, scope

I'm having trouble figuring out an error in Python that I haven't gotten in other languages that support functional programming. I have the following code:

```
def call_once(func):
  called = False
  def aux(*args, **kwargs):
    if called:
      raise Exception("This function was already called.")
    else:
      called = True
      return func(*args, **kwargs)
  return aux

@call_once
def add(x, y):
  return x + y
```

However, if I have:

```
add(1, 2)
```

I get:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'called' referenced before assignment
```

What's going on here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141642/what-limitations-have-closures-in-python-compared-to-language-x-closures probably would've been a better dupe candidate than the one I picked.

Comment: Try running it this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103773/efficient-way-of-having-a-function-only-execute-once-in-a-loop