# Variation of "running a function only once" in Python 3

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I'm using `rpy2` to wrap R libraries (modules in Python speak) within python, through the `importr` function provided by this module.

The issue is that `importr` can be **very** expensive at runtime (it does a number of things when invoked) and I'd like to have it called just once (for each `importr` call I have several functions using its result, and at the same time I can't just put everything on top of the module, or it would slow import time significantly).

Currently, for *each* module where I use `importr` I do:

```
myrlib = None

def do_stuff_with_r(param):
    global myrlib
    if myrlib is None:
        myrlib = importr(myrlib)
```

I'd like to generalize it since I do this kind of operation in many different modules and thus these lines are duplicated all over.

However I'm not sure how to do this: [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103773/efficient-way-of-having-a-function-only-execute-once-in-a-loop) returns None after the first invocation, which is not really what I'd like to do. Assuming this is doable, how do I ensure `importr()` for a specific argument is called just once?

Comment: note: Python `import` statement uses `sys.modules` i.e., if `myrlib` is a Python module (implemented however you like (pure Python, C, Fortran, etc)) then multiple imports of the same module are fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own wrapper function that caches the result of the import:

```
def import_r(lib, cache={}):
    if lib not in cache:
        cache[lib] = importr(lib)
    return cache[lib]
```

And use that every time you want want to use `importr` instead?

Comment: Wanted to, but I had to wait until the timer ran out. ;)

Comment: @Einar: to avoid unnecessary lookups `ret = cache.get(lib) \n if ret is None: ret = cache[lib] = importr(lib); \n return ret`. The general (perhaps slower) version is `functools.lru_cache()` decorator.