# How to instantiate an object once

Tags: python, object, testing, instantiation, pytest

I am instantiating this object below every time I call csv in my function. Was just wondering if there's anyway I could just instantiate the object just once?
I tried to split the return csv from def csv() to another function but failed.

**Code instantiating the object**

```
def csv():

    proj = Project.Project(db_name='test', json_file="/home/qingyong/workspace/Project/src/json_files/sys_setup.json")#, _id='poc_1'
    csv = CSVDatasource(proj, "/home/qingyong/workspace/Project/src/json_files/data_setup.json")
    return csv
```

**Test function**

```
def test_df(csv,df)
```

..............

Comment: `csvObj = csv() # since you're returning csv object in the function csv()`

Comment: How should i change my code? Advise?

Comment: Your "code to call function" is not calling the `csv` function, it is passing the `csv` function into `test_df`, you don't show it being called.  Maybe part of your confusion is that you have a name `csv` used inside the function of the same name - a bad idea.

Comment: I am missing another function to return the objects. What i want is like instantiate the objects once, have a function to return the objects and other test functions can get from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your `csv` function actually a `pytest.fixture`? If so, you can change its scope to `session` so it will only be called once per `py.test` session.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def csv():
    # rest of code
```

Of course, the returned data should be immutable so tests can't affect each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global variable to cache the object:

```
_csv = None

def csv():
    global _csv
    if _csv is None:
        proj = Project.Project(db_name='test', json_file="/home/qingyong/workspace/Project/src/json_files/sys_setup.json")#, _id='poc_1'
        _csv = CSVDatasource(proj, "/home/qingyong/workspace/Project/src/json_files/data_setup.json")
    return _csv
```

Another option is to change the caller to cache the result of `csv()` in a manner similar to the snippet above.

Note that your "code to call the function" doesn't call the function, it only declares another function that apparently receives the `csv` function's return value. You didn't show the call that actually calls the function.

Comment: it's a bad idea to use global right? Maybe I am missing another function to return the objects. What i want is like instantiate the objects once, have a function to return the objects and other test functions can get from it

Comment: @QingYong It's a bad idea to use a global as part of the public interface, or to pass data between module boundaries. Neither is the case here. Caching the return value of a function without exposing it in the interface is the correct (and necessary) use of global variables. This implementation "instantiates the object once", as requested.

Comment: @downvoter It is not obvious what is wrong with the response, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a decorator for this if `CSVDatasource` doesn't have side effects like reading the input line by line.

See [Efficient way of having a function only execute once in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103773/efficient-way-of-having-a-function-only-execute-once-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the object in the function's local dictionary. And return that object if it exists, create a new one if it doesn't.

```
def csv():
    if not hasattr(csv, 'obj'):
        proj = Project.Project(db_name='test', json_file="/home/qingyong/workspace/Project/src/json_files/sys_setup.json")#, _id='poc_1'
        csv.obj = CSVDatasource(proj, "/home/qingyong/workspace/Project/src/json_files/data_setup.json")
    return csv.obj
```