# How to restrict base class method to be run only once

Tags: python, oop

```
class car(object):
    def read_spec_and_populate_db():
        spec = read_from_file(spec.yaml)
        populate_db(spec)

class awd(car):
    super(awd, self).read_spec_and_populate_db()

    def foo(self):
    ...

class fwd(car):
    super(fwd, self).read_spec_and_populate_db()

    def bar(self):
    ...
```

Class `awd` and `fwd` can be instantiated at different times or only one of them can be instantiated. Now, is there a way to restrict the base class method read_spec_and_populate_db() to be executed only once?

I did lookup in SO and found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103773/efficient-way-of-having-a-function-only-execute-once-in-a-loop). Wanted to see if there are any other option.

Edit: Not that I'm against it. I'm looking for ideas apart from using a flag. My current implementation is using a flag in the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a flag:

```
class car(object):
    db_read = False
    def read_spec_and_populate_db():
        if not car.db_read:
            spec = read_from_file(spec.yaml)
            populate_db(spec)
            car.db_read = True
```

Now you can call `read_spec_and_populate_db()` as many times as you
want. It does its work only once.

Comment: And to explain: You'll have to keep track of "it has been read" some way, and a flag is a perfectly clear way to communicate exactly that. Don't do magic stuff just for the magic.

Comment: this is fine, except that a class method is cleaner IMO, no? If yes, update your answer and I'll delete mine. I've already upvoted yours

Comment: A classmethod does not work with inheritance. When you make an instance of `awk` first it creates `awk.populated = True`. Then when you make an instance of `car`, `car.populated` is still false and the specs will be read a second time.

Comment: Oh, really? So the scope of class level variables is only the one of its direct instances? Wow, didn't know that!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean class attribute flag to keep track of whether the method has been run already or not, like so:

```
class Car(object):
    _populated_db = False

    def read_spec_and_populate_db(self):
        if not self._populated_db:
            spec = read_from_file(spec.yaml)
            populate_db(spec)
            self._populated_db = True
```

Comment: Just out of interest, did you downvote because of that?

Comment: yes, because I don't see the point of having twice the same answer.

Answer (score -1):

One thought might be reassigning the name `read_spec_and_populate_db`, as the last step in its execution, to point to a method with the same signature but does nothing

```
class car(object):
    def _dummy(self):
        pass

    def read_spec_and_populate_db(self):
        spec = read_from_file(spec.yaml)
        populate_db(spec)

        self.read_spec_and_populate_db = self._dummy
```