# How to run function only once in a loop and infinitely?

Tags: python

I have a `while True` statement, and inside that I have a `for loop`.
I'd like to run the function `first_start` only once for each `app`.

I already tried the query below, but it don't seems to work:

```
while True:
    do_first_start = True
    for app in applications:
        if do_first_start:
            # Reloading page before start the bot
            await asyncio.create_task(first_start(app_name=bot))
            do_first_start = False
```

I also took a look on this question from [@Marcus Ottosson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103773/efficient-way-of-having-a-function-only-execute-once-in-a-loop), but I couldn't make it work as well.

My script:

```
while True:
    do_first_start = True
    for app in applications:
            bot = app.split(':')[1].strip()
            print('Going to bot: ' + str(bot))
            app = Desktop(backend="uia").windows(title=app)[0]
            app.set_focus()

            if do_first_start:
                # Reloading page before start the bot
                await asyncio.create_task(first_start(app_name=bot))
                do_first_start = False

            # Steps of this bot:
            # - Connect Wallet
            await asyncio.create_task(connect_wallet(app_name=bot))
            # - Login
            await asyncio.create_task(login_metamask(app_name=bot))
            # - Treasure Hunt
            await asyncio.create_task(treasure_hunt_game(refresh_only=True, app_name=bot))
            # - New map
            await asyncio.create_task(new_map(app_name=bot))
            # - Check for errors
            await asyncio.create_task(skip_error_on_game(app_name=bot))
```

What would be the best way to run the function only once in this case?

Comment: Write `app` to a set after you've called `first_start()` for that app. Test if `app` is already in the set before calling `first_start()`.

Comment: You're pretty close with the above, but you have to set the flag OUTSIDE of the while loop. The way you're doing it you're setting the flag to true on each iteration.

Comment: However, if you want to run *each* `app`, you need to wait until the `for` loop is done to set `do_first_start = False`.

Comment: Can `applications` change between iterations of the `while` loop?

Comment: @chepner No! applications don't change. And I'd like to run each `app` as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably just pull the code that starts the app out of the `while` loop altogether, then replace the `while` loop with an infinite sequence of repeating bots.

```
from itertools import cycle


# Iterate through applications *once*, starting the app
# and creating the related bot name for future use.
bots = []
for app in applications:
    bot = app.split(':')[1].strip()
    print('Going to bot: ' + str(bot))
    app = Desktop(backend="uia").windows(title=app)[0]
    app.set_focus()
    await asyncio.create_task(first_start(app_name=bot))
    bots.append((app, bot))

# Cycle through the bots in one loop rather than restarting
# the loop in an infinite loop.
for app, bot in cycle(bots): 
    app.set_focus()
    await asyncio.create_task(connect_wallet(app_name=bot))
    await asyncio.create_task(login_metamask(app_name=bot))
    await asyncio.create_task(treasure_hunt_game(refresh_only=True, app_name=bot))
    await asyncio.create_task(new_map(app_name=bot))
    await asyncio.create_task(skip_error_on_game(app_name=bot))
```

Comment: I didn't know this solution! Does `cycle` do the same as `while True`? `app` is the same `list ` as `bots` in this answer right? Should `cycle` run in `app list` instead of `bots` or not in this case?

Comment: `cycle` just creates an iterator that goes back to the beginning of the argument each time you finish one complete cycle. For example, `cycle([1,2])` yields `1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, ...`.

Comment: Your original `while` loop only used the actual value of `app` to create the value of `bot` and start the app; there's no need to do that repeatedly, so I saved the values of `bots` in the first loop to avoid reconstructing it each time from the original value of `app`.

Comment: Got it! Definitely your code looks better, however I still need to open the app in the loop using `app.set_focus()`, and use `bot` to run in those functions. What would be the best way in this case?

Comment: Should I change `applications` list to a nested list by appending `bot` into it (or chage to a dict)? So I can use both? Iterate `app` and `bot` then.

Comment: You can; I'm not sure I see the need to, since `app` isn't used in the second loop at all.

Comment: But `app` is being called only once after finishing `applications`, I need to call `app` in the `cycle` as well in order to call `app.set_focus()`, so I can run all `asyncio` functions.

Comment: Ok, then sure, a `dict` or list of pairs would be fine. (Not knowing what API you are using, it wasn't obvious that `app.set_focus()` was necessary for the subsequent calls.)

Comment: Updated to store a pair `(app, bot)` in the list `bots` for use in the second loop.

Comment: You're the man! Thank you very much.

Comment: I noticed that `app.set_focus()` is running before all `async` functions runs for each app. But I didn't understand why, can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag to keep track of whether this is the first iteration of the outer `while True` loop.  Initialize this flag to true, then set it to false at the end of the loop.

```
firstloop = True
while True:
    for app in applications:
        if firstloop:
            # run first_start for this app
        # do other stuff with this app
    firstloop = False
```