# TypeError when combining ABCMeta with __init_subclass__ in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm trying to use python 3.6's new `__init_subclass__` feature ([PEP 487](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/)) with the `abc` module. It doesn't seem to be working. The following code:

```
from abc import ABCMeta
class Initifier:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, x=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        print('got x', x)

class Abstracted(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    pass

class Thingy(Abstracted, Initifier, x=1):
    pass

thingy = Thingy()
```

yields the following when run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<filename>", line 10, in <module>
    class Thingy(Abstracted, Initifier, x=1):
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'x'
```

Everything works fine if Abstracted doesn't use the `ABCMeta` metaclass.

This error is fairly resilient, for example, the following code still fails with a similar type error (presumably because a metaclass' `__new__` runs at class instantiation time, whereas the parent class' `__new__` doesn't run until object instantiation).

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class Initifier:
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct, x=None, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct, **kwargs)

    def __init_subclass__(cls, x=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        print('got x', x)

class Abstracted(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    pass

class Thingy(Initifier, Abstracted, x=1):
    pass

thingy = Thingy()
```

Can anyone confirm that this is a bug in the Python 3.6 `abc` module and/or `__init_subclass__` implementation? (I might be using `__init_subclass__` wrong.) Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: That's a funny interaction in the new `__init_subclass__` design. Pretty much every metaclass in existence is now supposed to pass unexpected keyword arguments through to `super().__new__` so `type.__new__` can pass them to `__init_subclass__`, but ABCMeta and probably tons of other metaclasses don't do that.

Comment: That's probably going to be a headache for a while for anyone who wants to use `__init_subclass__` together with a metaclass they don't control.

Comment: I expect that this works if you reverse the order of inheritance, correct? Since `Initifier` will eat `x` before `Abstracted` sees it.

Comment: @RickTeachey incorrect, alas. It breaks with the same TypeError regardless of inheritance order.

Comment: huh. Well that sucks.

Comment: What if you reverse the order and add a call to `__new__` in `Initifier` and eat the `x` argument in there?

Comment: That also fails, surprisingly. (I'll edit the code into the OP momentarily.)

Comment: No nevermind it isn't surprising because the exception happens upon instantiation of the class, not a class instance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a bug in `abc.ABCMeta`, due to a wart in the design of `__init_subclass__`. I recommend reporting it.

Pretty much every metaclass in existence is now supposed to pass unexpected keyword arguments through to `super().__new__` so `type.__new__` can pass them to `__init_subclass__`, but ABCMeta and probably tons of other metaclasses don't do that yet. `abc.ABCMeta.__new__` chokes on the `x` keyword argument instead of passing it through, causing the exception you see.

Trying to use `__init_subclass__` keyword arguments with a metaclass that hasn't been updated for the new design isn't going to work. You'll have to wait for the metaclasses you use to be patched.