# Object Factory design to initialize parent or child class object

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I am building a tool that takes directories as inputs and performs actions where necessary. These actions vary depeding on certain variables so I created a few class objects which help me with my needs in an organised fashion.

However, I hit a wall figuring out how to best design the following scenario.

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume there are only directories (no files). Also, the below is a heavily simplified example.

I have the following parent class:

```py
# directory.py
from pathlib import Path

class Directory:
    def __init__(self, absolute_path):
        self.path = Path(absolute_path)

    def content(self):
        return [Directory(c) for c in self.path.iterdir()]
```

So, I have a method in the parent class that returns `Directory` instances for each directory inside the initial directory in *`absolute_path`*

What the above does, is hold all methods that can be performed on all directories. Now, I have a separate class that inherits from the above and adds further methods.

```py
# special_directory.py
from directory import Directory

class SpecialDirectory(Directory):
    def __init__(self, absolute_path):
        super().__init__(absolute_path)

    # More methods
```

I am using an Object Factory like approach to build one or the other based on a condition like so:

```py
# directory_factory.py
from directory import Directory
from special_directory import SpecialDirectory

def pick(path):
    return SpecialDirectory(path) if 'foo' in path else Directory(path)
```

So, if `'foo'` exists in the path, it should be a `SpecialDirectory` instead allowing it to do everything `Directory` does plus more.

The problem I'm facing is with the `content()` method. Both should be able to do that but I don't want it to be limited to making a list of `Directory` instances. If any of its content has `"foo*"`, it should be a `SpecialDirectory`.

`Directory` doesn't (and shouldn't) know about `SpecialDirectory`, so I tried importing and using the factory but it complains about some circular import (which makes sense).

I am not particularly stuck as I have come up with a temp fix, but it isn't pretty. So I was hoping I could get some tips as to what would be an effective and clean solution for this specific situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is sometimes called a "virtual constructor" which is a way to allow subclasses to determine what type of class instance is created when calling the base class constructor. There's no such thing in Python (or C++ for that matter), but you can simulate them. Below is an example of a way of doing this.

Note this code is very similar to what's in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28076300/355230) to the question titled *[Improper use of `__new__` to generate classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035685/improper-use-of-new-to-generate-classes)* (which has more information about the technique). Also see the one to [What exactly is a Class Factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2949205/355230)

```
from pathlib import Path


class Directory:

    subclasses = []

    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.subclasses.append(cls)

    def __init__(self, absolute_path):
        self.path = Path(absolute_path)

    def __new__(cls, path):
        """ Create instance of appropriate subclass. """
        for subclass in cls.subclasses:
            if subclass.pick(path):
                return object.__new__(subclass)
        else:
            return object.__new__(cls)  # Default is this base class.

    def content(self):
        return [Directory(c) for c in self.path.iterdir()]

    def __repr__(self):
        classname = type(self).__name__
        return f'{classname}(path={self.path!r})'

    # More methods
    ...


class SpecialDirectory(Directory):
    def __init__(self, absolute_path):
        super().__init__(absolute_path)

    @classmethod
    def pick(cls, path):
        return 'foo' in str(path)

    # More methods
    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = './_obj_factory_test'
    d = Directory(root)
    print(d.content())
```

Comment: Oh, this looks very interesting. Gonna do some further reading. I came across the `__new__` method upon my research but not the subclass magic. I kinda stopped looking into this further because there seems to be some people who disagree with having a class constructor returning an instance of a different type (a child in this case).

Comment: The question [Improper use of __new__ to generate classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035685/improper-use-of-new-to-generate-classes) may have been asked for the same reason (which I mention I disagree with in my answer to it). The idea of virtual constructors has been around for quite a while, so you should research it, too (because that's what this is — and it's another name for the Object Factory design pattern).

Comment: P.S. I got the idea of using `__init_subclass__()` to register subclasses from a section in the [PEP 487 -- Simpler customisation of class creation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/#subclass-registration) proposal which was implemented in Python 3.6.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for all the info! It's been very educational!
Just one question if you don't mind me asking for future reference. If it happens that I know that there will only be one subclass, is there any reason you would recommend against skipping the whole `subclass` malarky, and in the `__new__` method do the comparison by doing `if SpecialDirectory.pick(path):` directly?
*EDIT*
I posted the comment right after you threw the last comment which pretty much responded this haha. Thanks again!

Comment: The downside to doing that is it violates encapsulation and means the base class knows about its subclasses. If you're going to do that, might as well just create a factory function that knows about all the subclasses. The main point is about the ability to add additional subclasses without needing to modify the base class (or a separate factory function).

Comment: Of course. I do want to avoid that. I can mark this as answered. Happy with what I learned! Thanks again!