# How to make the class constructor that returns the object of child class?

Tags: python, class

I'm coding in Python. I have a `Base` class which contains several methods. There are some child classes; they may have their own methods. I want the `Base` class constructor to create the object not of the class itself but the object of one of the child classes depending on the argument.

For example, guess our child classes are `Point`, `Line`, and `Plane`, all are inherited from `Base`, and the difference between them is set by the `dim` attribute of the `Base` class.

```
class Base():
    
    def __init__(self, dim, a, b):
        self.dim = dim
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        
class Point(Base):
    
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(1, a, b)
        
class Line(Base):
    
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(2, a, b)
        
class Plane(Base):
    
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(3, a, b)
```

If I explicitly create a `Point`, the object type will be `Point`:

```
pointA = Point(0, 0)
type(pointA) # __main__.Point
```

But if I do the same through the `Base` constructor, the object will be of class `Base`:

```
pointB = Base(1, 0, 0)
type(pointB) # __main__.Base
```

So I'd like to change this behavior and make the `Base` constructor return a `Point`, `Line` or `Plane` object if the `dim` attribute is equal to 1, 2 or 3 respectively. How can I do this?

**EDIT:**
Based on this thread ([Improper use of __new__ to generate class instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035685/improper-use-of-new-to-generate-class-instances)) I overrid the `Base.__new__()` and got the following code:

```
class Base():
    
    def __new__(cls, a, b, dim):
        if dim == 1:
            return object.__new__(Point)
        elif dim == 2:
            return object.__new__(Line)
        elif dim == 3:
            return object.__new__(Plane)    
        
class Point(Base):
    
    def __init__(self, a, b, dim):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        
class Line(Base):
    
    def __init__(self, a, b, dim):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        
class Plane(Base):
    
    def __init__(self, a, b, dim):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

The code above works, but it requires an explicit setting of the `dim` argument even when I create a new `Point` instance. A non-identical set of arguments in `Base.__new__()` and `Point.__init__()` raises an error. How can I keep this behavior but remove `dim` from the `Point` constructor?

Comment: It's generally expected that `type(MyClass(...)) is MyClass` in Python, better not to violate this unwritten rule. It sounds like you may want a factory function, not a type.

Comment: I understand that what I want may contradict good practice, but I'm still wishing to find a way to do that. And I'd like to keep the different classes so that their constructors could be called directly. Right now, when I need to create an object inside a code, I call a function that checks `dim` and either calls one of the subclasses constructors or raises an error (`if not (dim in [1,2,3])`). I'd like to generalize the solution and ban the creation of the Base objects even if the Base constructor is called.

Comment: @wim: I beg to differ, there is not such rule.

Comment: @martineau The datamodel docs say the return value of `object.__new__(cls[, ...])` should _usually_ be an instance of `cls`. Deviating from this has often been a design flaw. To name a couple: [bpo40185](https://bugs.python.org/issue40185) / [GH-19371](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/19371) refactored it out of `typing.NamedTuple` for Python 3.9, and [bpo24132](https://bugs.python.org/issue24132) has some ongoing efforts to allow `pathlib.Path` subclasses for Python 3.11. I'd caution against `__new__` returning a different type, unless there's an extremely convincing reason to do so.

Comment: @wim: Deviating from what is commonly done is not automatically a design flaw. Nor does having the `new()` method of the class return a subclass violate [Liskov's substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). I have successfully used the design pattern in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28076300/355230) to the duplicate question  numerous times since first learning about it — see my answer to [What exactly is a Class Factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2949205/355230). Like any tool or technique it can be used inappropriately.

Comment: @martineau: your answer to the duplicate question really helped. However, I still don't understand how to make it work if I want to have a different set of arguments when creating `Base` and `Point` instances. E.g., if I want to exclude `dim` argument from `Point` constructor. Could you please clarify it?

Comment: @martineau I didn't say it was automatically a design flaw, and never even mentioned LSP (your logical fallacy is: [strawman](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/strawman)). But doing this with the constructors _correctly_ is difficult to implement, and the evidence is there that it can cause problems with inheritance, so a simple factory method is usually a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

You don't typically want to do this by instantiating a base case. While I suppose you could override [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__), I wouldn't advise it for this. Notably, though, `__init__` *has a None return type*. So, regardless, you can't do this in `__init__` - the object is already created at that point.

Instead, what you probably want is a static so-called 'Factory' method on your base class:

```
from typing import Type

class Base():

    @staticmethod
    def create(dim, a, b) -> Type[Base]:
        # Decide which subclass you want to create, instantiate and return it.

...
new_obj = Base.create(x, y, z)
```

Comment: the implementation of the static function depends on the dimension (if-elif cases) returning each a different class so the type-hint is wrong [Also the implementation of the other class should be slightly different]

Comment: Fair enough re: type hint. Fixed. Not sure what you meant by 'other class', though.

Comment: with other classes I mean Point, Line, Plane

Comment: @cards Then I’m not clear what you mean by slightly different?

Comment: Now the OP edit the question with the updated classes (no super(), and co.). Just this:)