# Import subclass from a base class in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, import, subclass, radix

I have a base class that has a method that creates an instance of a subclass that is called the same as the input string.

This worked before by putting the subclasses and the base class in the same file, and doing something like `globals()[name]`.

Now, however, I've split up the subclasses into other files.  They each have an `import base` statement at the top, so I can't just simply import the subclasses in my base class or there'll be a chain of circular importing.

Is there any workaround for this?

In **base.py**:

```
from basefactory import BaseFactory
class Base:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        ...
    def resolve(self, element):
        className = typing.getClassName(element)
        return BaseFactory.getInstance(className, element, self)
```

In **basefactory.py**:

```
from file1 import *
from file2 import *
...
class BaseFactory:
    @staticmethod
    def getInstance(name, arg1, arg2):
       subclass = globals()[name]
       return subclass(arg1, arg2)
```

In **file1.py**:

```
from base import Base

class subclass1(Base):
    def foo(self):
        return self.arg1
```

Comment: Is resolve() just for determining the class type, and returning a new instance of itself?

Comment: It returns an instance of a subclass of Base.

Comment: What about moving resolve into the factory class, which is responsible for returning the correct instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can move the `import` statement that is failing to the method that creates the subclass object.

Comment: While this works, what is the performance impact of this?  Wouldn't re-importing 60 subclasses every time the method is called (it's done recursively a lot) be expensive?

Comment: Imported modules are cached in `sys.modules`, so I wouldn't expect any significant impact.

Comment: Also, I have to do something along the lines of `from package.filename import *` for each file.  In the future, I would have to remember to add more imports every time I add a new file.  Is there a more compact syntax for importing all members of all modules of a package?

Comment: You can do "import package", and then reference objects as package.filename.member1, package.filename2.member2, etc.

Comment: Since my subclass instance creator is automatic (based on strings), I don't know in which file the subclass is in.

Comment: If you don't know in which module the subclass implementation will be located beforehand, then you'll need to implement some kind of discovery mechanism. In any case, if I understand correctly, since your classes aren't going to be provided by third party libraries, it could be enough to add them to `__all__` in the package `__init__.py` and import using `from  package import *` (that requires some maintenance, though).

Answer (score 7):

From what I'm understanding, you have:

1. A base class
2. A series of derived classes from the base class
3. A factory method in the base class that instantiates the correct type of derived class
4. The derived classes have been split into files, and they depend on the base class, but the factory method in the base class depends on the derived classes

One solution would be to create a separate function / class for the factory method, and put it in a separate file from the base class. This file could import all the files for the base class and derived classes without the circular reference.

For example:

```
# base.py:
class baseClass():
   def __init__(self):
      self.name = "Base"

# sub1.py:
from base import baseClass
class sub1Class(baseClass):
   def __init__(self):
      self.name = "sub1"

# sub2.py:
from base import baseClass
class sub2Class(baseClass):
   def __init__(self):
      self.name = "sub2"

# factory.py:
from sub1 import sub1Class
from sub2 import sub2Class # should not create an error
mapping = {'sub1': sub1Class, 'sub2': sub2Class}

def create(baseType):
  return mapping[baseType]
```

Actually, a better method might be to use [type](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type):

`type(name, bases, dict)` returns a new type object. This is essentially a dynamic form of the class statement. The name string is the class name and becomes the `__name__` attribute; the bases tuple itemizes the base classes and becomes the `__bases__` attribute; and the `dict` dictionary is the namespace containing definitions for class body and becomes the `__dict__` attribute. For example, the following two statements create identical type objects:

```
>>> class X(object):
...     a = 1
...
>>> X = type('X', (object,), dict(a=1))
```

Why not move resolve into a manager class? Have a look at the domain class in [Class factory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456672/class-factory-in-python). I'm not sure if resolve is needed... you can get the class name directly from `self.__class__.__name__`, and use python functions like `type()` and `isinstance()` to check if they're particular types.

Also check out:
[Can you use a string to instantiate a class in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553784/can-you-use-a-string-to-instantiate-a-class-in-python)
[Does python have an equivalent to Java Class.forName()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname)

Comment: This just propagates the importing error to the factory class.  
Since the factory class just does `from sub1 import *`, `from sub2 import *`..., and each subclass does `from base import *`, this will throw an ImportError after attempting to import sub2.  Trying to catch the exception and pass it means that all the other imports will be skipped.

Comment: Unless you put the factory class in it's own file.

Comment: Another solution might be to keep better control of your subclasses, and create a dict that specifies the mapping between the string and your derived class, and import each of your 60 base classes into the factory class explicitly.

Comment: I did this - my factory class imports everything from each subclass (which imports the base class).  Meanwhile, my base class, which is in a separate file, imports the factory class.  This still results in a circular import.

Comment: The base class shouldn't need to know about the factory class.  Perhaps you could post some code on how they're intertwined?

Comment: This question had some interesting tips on class factories: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456672/class-factory-in-python

Comment: The method you gave does not work for the example code I posted, because the base class calls into the factory class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you,
why do you take the subclasses out of the class if you need them inside? Let then inside the class and, wherever you need them, you can `from class import subclass`

Comment: I have over 60 subclasses.  Before, when they were in the same file as my base class, the file was over 800 LOC.  It was more or less impossible to find things.

Comment: 60 subclasses!! what are they for?