# Changing the class type of a class after inserted data

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I want to create a class in python, which should work like this:

1. Data assigned, maybe bound to a variable (eg `a = exampleclass(data)` or just `exampleclass(data)`)
2. Upon being inserted data, it should automatically determine some properties of the data, and if some certain properties are fullfilled, it will automatically...
3. ... change class to another class

The part 3 is the part that i have problem with. How do i really change the class inside of the class? for example:

If I have two classes, one is `Small_Numbers`, and the other is `Big_numbers`; now I want any `small_number` smaller than 1000 to be transferred into a `Big_number` and vice versa, testcode:

```
a = Small_number(50)
type(a) # should return Small_number.
b = Small_number(234234)
type(b) # should return Big_number.
c = Big_number(2)
type(c) # should return Small_number.
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: oh thanks for that, i looked now at the changes you did, and it's obvious it was needed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) is the usual way to solve this, *especially* since instantiating a class is indistinguishable from calling a function in Python.

However, if you *really* want, you can assign to `self.__class__`:

```
THRESHOLD = 1000

class Small(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        if n < THRESHOLD:
            self.n = n
        else:
            self.__class__ = Big
            self.__init__(n)

class Big(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        if n < THRESHOLD:
            self.__class__ = Small
            self.__init__(n)
        else:
            self.n = n
```

This works as expected:

```
>>> a = Small(100)
>>> type(a)
<class 'Small'>
>>> b = Small(1234)
>>> type(b)
<class 'Big'>
>>> c = Big(2)
>>> type(c)
<class 'Small'>
```

If assigning to `self.__class__` seems too strange, then [you can override `__new__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) instead. This method is called before `__init__` is called and it can be used to pick the class to instantiate:

```
THRESHOLD = 1000

class Switcher(object):
    def __new__(cls, n):
        if n < THRESHOLD:
            new_cls = Small
        else:
            new_cls = Big
        instance = super(Switcher, new_cls).__new__(new_cls, n)
        if new_cls != cls:
            instance.__init__(n)
        return instance

class Small(Switcher):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

class Big(Switcher):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
```

Comment: This approach is very cool, but it doesn't work 100% of the time: you can get "TypeError: \_\_class\_\_ assignment: 'X' object layout differs from 'Y'" from time to time, if your class bases aren't carefully chosen.

Comment: @RomanSusi: good point! I can see [in the Python source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/443772a82dcd/Objects/typeobject.c#l3146) that you will get this error if the classes use different `__slots__`. This is also mentioned at the [bottom of this section](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots) of the manual.

Comment: I think I got many good answers to this question, but I loved this one! especially the first half. I think it's wonderful solution and works just like I want it to. Btw this works without (object) for python 3

Comment: I highly recommend *not* to change the object's type (i.e., not to assign to `__class__`). See [this comment from the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#id5), and consider that special methods may work unpredictably after you do that. Even if you think you know exactly what will happen, you're ok with that, you may get screwed with the next version of Python - after all, there's no clear promise from Python how exactly it will (or will not) work.

Comment: @max: Yeah, the solution involving `__class__` assignment is also my least favorite.

Comment: The solution in which you override `__new__` needs to either check that new_cls is not a subclass of cls (`if not issubclass(client_cls, cls)`), or else do something other than calling `__init__` as this will cause the `__init__` for the subclass to be called twice.  You can test this by adding a print statement into the `__init__` for each of the subclasses.

Answer (score 15):

Why not using a factory method? This one will decide which class to instanciate depending on the passed data. Using your example:

```
def create_number(number):
    if number < 1000:
        return SmallNumber(number)
    return BigNumber(number)
```

Comment: Yeah, or `(SmallNumber if number < 1000 else BigNumber)(number)`.

Answer (score 11):

Don't. Use a factory function instead.

```
def create_number(source):
    if source < 1000:
       return Small_number(source)
    else:
       return Big_number(source)

a = create_number(50)
b = create_number(234234)
c = create_number(2)
```