# Python: Programatically create subclasses based on __init__ values

Tags: python, dynamic, inner-classes

I have a base class from which I would like to make many subclasses. The subclasses differ only in the arguments used to call the base class during instantiation. The example below shows how to make a subclass `Apple`. Is there a way to do this programatically, without having to code the subclass' `__init__` method? This seems like a job for metaclasses, but in this case I cannot modify the base class.

```
apple = {'color': 'red', 'shape': 'sphere'}
pear = {'color': 'yellow', 'shape': 'cone'}
melon = {'color': 'green', 'shape': 'prolate'}

class Fruit(object):
    def __init__(self, color, shape):
        self.color = color
        self.shape = shape        

class Apple(Fruit):
    def __init__(self):
        Fruit.__init__(self, **apple)
```

Comment: If they only differ by initial values, what's the point of them being subtypes? Why not just `def apple(): return Fruit("red", "sphere")`?

Comment: What is the motivation for wanting to use subclasses? This appears like an obvious use case for instances of `Fruit`, not subclasses.

Comment: The internal representation should not define the API; so if OP wants subclasses, there might be a reason.

Comment: There are reasons, but I admit they're pretty trivial: the code where the subclasses are used is much clearer if the classes bear the names of their object, and I was simply curious if this was possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the type() function.

```
def make_fruit(name, kwargs):
    def my_init(self):
        Fruit.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    return type(name, (Fruit,), {'__init__': my_init})

Apple = make_fruit('Apple', apple)
```

Comment: Nicer.  And I like using `def` instead of `lambda` for defining the `__init__()`.

Comment: I prefer this over @falsetru's response since it doesn't use a ``lambda``. Using the ``dict`` argument in ``type`` to define ``__init__`` is the key. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using [type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type):

```
class Fruit(object):
    def __init__(self, color, shape):
        self.color = color
        self.shape = shape        

apple = {'color': 'red', 'shape': 'sphere'}
pear = {'color': 'yellow', 'shape': 'cone'}
melon = {'color': 'green', 'shape': 'prolate'}

g = globals()
for clsname, attrs in [('Apple', apple), ('Pear', pear), ('Melon', melon)]:
    def temp(attrs):
        g[clsname] = type(clsname, (Fruit,), {
            '__init__': lambda self: Fruit.__init__(self, **attrs)
        })
    temp(attrs)
```

---

```
>>> a = Apple()
>>> p = Pear()
>>> m = Melon()
>>> assert a.color == 'red' and a.shape == 'sphere'
>>> assert p.color == 'yellow' and p.shape == 'cone'
>>> assert m.color == 'green' and m.shape == 'prolate'
```

Comment: Good solution (I can abort my writing then …).  But I have to disapprove of modifying the result of `globals()`.  This is not working in all cases.  (`locals()` isn't any better.)  There are lot of Qs in SO about this.  The only really working way of changing the current scope programmatically is via `exec` and that's an ugly hack.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution you're seeking does not exists: I all you subclasses share the same constructor, then the only thing which makes the class unique is its name. And I don't think you want to have a generic constructor which check the class name to choose what to do.

So I think:

- either you re-define the constructor in each subclass, and precise which parameter to pass to the parent constructor,
- either you put the specific constant values in some class member, and the constructor use it to call the parent constructor

See interesting thing in this other thread: [Class factory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456672/class-factory-in-python)